# How to stop my footer from sliding off when zooming in?

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with my page which when i zoom in or zoom out the footer and the forms just slide off where i wanted it to be. Is there anyway of solving the issue? I've tried surfing the internet for solutions but didnt work for me.
Thanks in advance for any help.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Registration Form</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">        
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <header>
                <h1>Registration Form</h1>
                <hr>
            </header>
            <article>
                <form action="#">
                    <label for="FirstName"><b>First Name:</b></label>
                    <input name="FirstName" type="text" placeholder="John" required>
                    <label for="LastName"><b>Last Name:</b></label>
                    <input name="LastName" type="text" placeholder="Doe" required>
                    <label for="email"><b>Email:</b></label>
                    <input name="email" type="text" placeholder="example@mail.com" required>
                    <label for="password"><b>Password:</b></label>
                    <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password here." required>
                    <p></p>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </form>
            </article>
            <footer>
                Copyright @ 2017 Your name here
            </footer>
        </div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
header h1 {
    text-align: center;
    margin: -60px 0 10px 0;
}

hr {
    margin: 0 -80px 0 -80px;
}

form input {
    display: block;
}

body {
    background-color: gray;
}

html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0; }

article  {
    margin: 50px 0 0 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}

footer {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    margin: 68px -80px 0 -80px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#container {
    padding: 80px;
    background-color: white;
    width: 600px;
    height: 259px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `#container`, I removed your `width: 600px` because it was preventing responsiveness and added `max-width: 100%`.

```
#container {
    padding: 80px;
    background-color: white;
    height: 259px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Check it out!
<s>https://jsfiddle.net/5x48bzo5/</s>

EDIT: Here is the new JSFiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/5x48bzo5/3/

Comment: I tried but didnt work, unfortunately, when i zoom in or out the footer still slips off. Thanks for the help tho

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Could you take a screenshot and show me the problem? I can't reproduce it on JSFiddle.

Comment: Can you hold ctrl then scroll your mouse wheel up and down in the output? What i meant by my problem was the footer (black bars at the bottom of the page) will slip off the default position when i zoom in (like 110%,etc..)

Comment: No worries! Keep on coding!